# Microsoft Teams Silencing Soundflower

Tags: audio, mojave, ms-office, soundflower

I am getting very odd behaviour from Soundflower while in a Microsoft Teams Meeting using the native app.

When I am not in a Teams Meeting, the system volume for Soundflower remains where set (see below)

[image: Soundflower Input Gain While NOT in Teams Meeting]

When I join a Teams meeting, Soundflower volume slider snaps to 0 (see below).

[image: Soundflower Input Gain While in Teams Meeting]

This is happening on macOS 10.14.6 and is constrained to just Teams, for instance, recording the Soundflower output through Quicktime is absolutely fine.

**Update:**

For clarity the sound settings in Teams are

- Output: Built-in Output
- Input: Soundflower 2ch

The output of another program is routed to Soundflower 2ch.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the snapshots of devices section of Teams app to the question? I believe you have activated custom setup on settings. It might come handy to people trying to help. Teams app on mac is rather laggy when it comes to sound equipment, in my case i hear everything through the headphone jack rather than my soundcard.

Comment: It is a custom setup, in that it is not using the built-in audio options.

Comment: The input is from Soundflower and the output is to built in audio output

Comment: Which app you want to connect to MS Teams?

Comment: Any, this currently happens with any app that has the ability to specify audio IO

Comment: How come your windows look blue?

Comment: @theonlygusti I don't quite follow I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

As of Microsoft Teams Version `1.3.00.30874`, this is no longer occurring on macOS Mojave 10.14.6